# How to define conditional text color in Text widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

[image]

I want to get specific color when  **nDataList.temp >= temp**

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you please attach your complete code

Comment: remove const before TextStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to null safety if `nDataList.temp` allows null you can't do the check as you did, the solution could be

```
Text(
  (nDataList.temp ?? 0) >= temp ? 'Normal' : 'Not Normal',
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 12,
    color: (nDataList.temp ?? 0) >= temp ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your commandline:

First, `flutter clean`

Then `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, my problem in **const** before **TextStyle()** widget